# How to remove localstorage data by an id in an array object

Tags: javascript, react-hooks, local-storage

```
const [dataAll, setDataAll] = useLocalStorage('localData', [
    {
        id: '',
        myName: '',
        roninAddress: '',
        manager: '',
        scholar: '',
        data: {
            slp: {
                total: '',
                claimableTotal: '',
                lastClaimedItemA: '',
                todaySoFar: '',
                yesterdaySLP: '',
            },
            leaderboard: {
                winRate: '',
                winTotal: '',
                drawTotal: '',
                loseTotal: '',
                elo: '',
                rank: '',
                name: '',
            },
        },
    },
]);

useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData() {
            localStorage.setItem('localData', JSON.stringify(dataAll));
        }
        fetchData();
    }, [dataAll]);

{dataAll.map((singleData) => {
                        const id = singleData.id;
                        const myName = singleData.myName;
                        const manager = singleData.manager;
                        const scholar = singleData.scholar;
                        const roninAddress = singleData.roninAddress;
                        const totalSlp = singleData.data.slp.total;
                        const claimableTotal = singleData.data.slp.claimableTotal;
                        const lastClaimedItemAt = singleData.data.slp.lastClaimedItemAt;
                        const todaySoFar = singleData.data.slp.todaySoFar;
                        const yesterdaySLP = singleData.data.slp.yesterdaySLP;
                        // const winRate = singleData.data.leaderboard.winRate;
                        // const winTotal = singleData.data.leaderboard.winTotal;
                        // const drawTotal = singleData.data.leaderboard.drawTotal;
                        // const loseTotal = singleData.data.leaderboard.lostTotal;
                        const elo = singleData.data.leaderboard.elo;
                        const rank = singleData.data.leaderboard.rank;
                        const name = singleData.data.leaderboard.name;

                        const unixTimeStamp = lastClaimedItemAt;
                        const dateTimeFormat = 'MMMM Do, YYYY h:mm ss A';
                        const datetime = usertz.datetime(unixTimeStamp, dateTimeFormat);

                        const newUnixTimeStamp = lastClaimedItemAt + 1209600;
                        const newdatetime = usertz.datetime(
                            newUnixTimeStamp,
                            dateTimeFormat
                        );

                        const totalSlpPrice = price * totalSlp;
                        const finaltotalSlpPrice = totalSlpPrice.toFixed(2);
                        return (
                            <Card
                                style={{
                                    width: '22rem',
                                    backgroundColor: '#4f4f4f',
                                    padding: '20px',
                                    marginTop: '30px',
                                    marginRight: '10px',
                                }}
                                key={singleData.id}
                            >
                                <Card.Body>
                                    <Card.Title className="text-center">{name}</Card.Title>
                                    Scholar: <span className="font-weight-bold">{myName}</span>
                                    <p className="address">
                                        {' '}
                                        <img src={ronin} alt="ronin" height="20px"></img>{' '}
                                        {roninAddress}
                                    </p>
                                    <Card.Subtitle className="mb-2 text-muted"></Card.Subtitle>
                                    <Row>
                                        <Card.Text
                                            as={Col}
                                            className="text-center bg-secondary rounded p-2 m-1 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center"
                                        >
                                            <div>
                                                In-Game SLP
                                                <h2>
                                                    <span style={{ color: '#3cf0cb' }}>{totalSlp}</span>
                                                    <img height="35px" src={slp} alt={slp}></img>
                                                </h2>
                                                <p>USD {finaltotalSlpPrice}</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </Card.Text>
                                        <Card.Text
                                            as={Col}
                                            className="text-center bg-secondary rounded p-2 m-1 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center"
                                        >
                                            <div>
                                                Claimable SLP
                                                <h2>
                                                    <span style={{ color: '#3cf0cb' }}>
                                                        {claimableTotal}
                                                        <img height="35px" src={slp} alt={slp}></img>
                                                    </span>
                                                </h2>
                                            </div>
                                        </Card.Text>
                                    </Row>
                                    Previos Claim: {datetime}
                                    <br />
                                    Next Claim: {newdatetime}
                                    <Card.Text className="bg-dark p-1">
                                        MMR ⚔️ : {elo}
                                        <br />
                                        Rank  : {rank}
                                        <br />
                                        SLP Today: {todaySoFar}
                                        <br />
                                        SLP Yesterday: {yesterdaySLP}
                                        <br />
                                    </Card.Text>
                                    <Card.Text className="p-2 bg-dark">
                                        Manager: {manager} % <br />
                                        Scholar: {scholar} %
                                    </Card.Text>
                                </Card.Body>
                                <Button></Button>
                            </Card>

<Button onClick={onRemove}></Button>
                            );
                        })}
```

[image]

How can I create a button to DELETE the localstorage array object by id by passing in from the button with the id from mapping? or getting from localstorage

```
const onRemove = (index) => {
    var newList = dataAll;
    newList.splice(index, 1);
    localStorage.setItem('localData', JSON.stringify([...newList]));
    window.location.reload(false);
};
```

I have created a button where can retrieve an id from mapping. How can I use the id to remove the localstorage by array id, not the index? Can refer to the image for more info. Using a randomly generated id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find index from localSotage object and pass `id` to `onRemove` function.

```
const onRemove = (id) => {
    let localData = localSotage.getItem('localData');
    let newList = JSON.parse(localData)
    let index = newList.findIndex(item => item.id === id)
    newList.splice(index, 1);
    localStorage.setItem('localData', JSON.stringify(newList));
   ...Other operations
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter by id.

And in `JSON.stringify([...newList])`, I don't know why you create a new array from `newList`? Just set `localData` by `newList`.

```js
const onRemove = (id) => {
    var newList = dataAll.filter(e => e.id !== id);
    localStorage.setItem('localData', JSON.stringify(newList));
    window.location.reload(false);
};
```

This is another version to improve your delete action. Because when you delete an item by Id, I think you should remove it out of `dataAll` variable also.

```js
const onRemove = (id) => {
        dataAll = dataAll.filter(e => e.id !== id);
        localStorage.setItem('localData', JSON.stringify(dataAll));
        window.location.reload(false);
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling Button's on click method `onRemove` passing the `id` to be removed:

```
<Button onClick={() => onRemove(id)}></Button>
```

And your method just need to call `setDataAll` with the filtered array:

```
const onRemove = id => setDataAll(dataAll.filter(sd => sd.id !== id))
```

That will execute the `useEffect` after change the value of `dataAll` and will update the localStorage key `localData`

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to get that array from localStorage and then make changes that you want to do with Array(In this case remove array with specific id) and then store that array to the same key.

```
const onRemove = (index) => {
    let localData = localSotage.getItem('localData');
    let newList = JSON.parse(localData)
    let index = newList.findIndex(item => item.id === index)
    newList.splice(index, 1);
    localStorage.setItem('localData', JSON.stringify(newList));
};
```

And also you need to pass id to the function when you click button so:

```
<Button onClick={() => onRemove(id)}></Button>
```